# Kill a multiprocessing pool with SIGKILL instead of SIGTERM (I think)

Tags: python, selenium, unix, multiprocessing

So, I have this program that utilizes multiprocessing with multiple selenium browser windows.

Here's what the program looks like:

```
pool = Pool(5)
results = pool.map_async(worker,range(10))
time.sleep(10)
pool.terminate()
```

However, this waits for the existing process in pool to complete. I want instant termination of all the workers.

Comment: Did you try `pool.kill()`?

Comment: Unfortunately Pool object has no attribute 'kill'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Pool` store worker processes list in `Pool._pool` attr, send a signal to them is straightforward then:

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import signal


def kill(pool):
    # stop repopulating new child
    pool._state = multiprocessing.pool.TERMINATE
    pool._worker_handler._state = multiprocessing.pool.TERMINATE
    for p in pool._pool:
        os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
    # .is_alive() will reap dead process
    while any(p.is_alive() for p in pool._pool):
        pass
    pool.terminate()
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work for me (Python 3) =( My main process gets stuck on the call to `terminate`. I have yet to find why

Comment: @Dici I have re-tested it under python3.7, found no error.

Comment: @georgexsh could you share your example test in a gist or pastebin to see if I can reproduce/compare with my situation? Specifically the issue for me occurs when there still are running tasks on the pool, I would like all of them to stop immediately and the program to exit

Comment: @Dici https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V6r9t85h7Z/, or you could provide [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it this evening. My code is a bit complex, it would take a bit of time to simplify it down to something shareable and doing so might eliminate what is preventing my pool to die. Let's see what your snippet can help me figure out :)

Comment: if a worker process wont exit after SIGKILL, it might be blocked on disk io, in D state.