# Python multiprocessing OSError even when terminating processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am running a large application which spawns and then destroys multiprocessing pools at times. I am sometimes forced to destroy these pools on-demand, even if processes in a pool are currently working on tasks. For this, I use a combination of close, terminate, and join.

```
pool.close()
pool.terminate()
pool.join()
```

I am seeing that, if the pools are in fact busy working when I call this sequence of commands, the processes aren't actually killed. Eventually, this results in an OSError for too many open files because the processes aren't cleaned up properly:

```
File "python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 66, in _launch
   parent_r, child_w = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

I logged the multiprocessing DEBUG output to stderr, which is attached. I am running on OSX. Does anyone have any ideas? I was under the impression that terminate **always** kills all processes in the pool and releases their OS resources.

Log Output: https://pastebin.com/raw/uXP3XusY

**UPDATE**: I did identify a single task which is sent out into the pool which, *if removed*, fixes the issue. Unfortunately, I don't see anything unusual that would cause this particular task to cause the pool to not be properly disposed of. Even if I wait for the task in question to finish by calling .get() on the ApplyResult, the issue persists.

Comment: Hmm. Pool forwards the `.terminate()` to the individual processes, which essentially sends them `SIGTERM` (assuming *nix). Do your processes block signals? Note that .e.g. `thread.join()` on the main thread block signals ...

Comment: I don't believe my processes are blocking signals, though I suppose I can't say for sure...I removed the calls to join() from the main thread, but that did not resolve the issue. Is it possible to manually kill all of the processes in the pool?

Comment: @dhke I just posted a slight update...I identified a particular task that's being applied to the pool which seems to be the source of the problem, but looking at what the task does, nothing seems suspicious...

Comment: Yes, you can send [signals too pool processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553120/kill-a-multiprocessing-pool-with-sigkill-instead-of-sigterm-i-think) with some work. `SIGKILL` cannot be ignored.

Comment: FWIW, errno 24 on MacOS is `EMFILE`, too many open files in process, which means that the process calling `os.pipe` here has reached its open-file-descriptor limit which appears to default to 256. It could be worth poking around to see which file descriptors are open, and why.